# Calculus: Finding Volume with Triple Integrals

Tags: calculus, integration, bounds-of-integration

**Problem:**A shape is bounded by the following elliptical function $4x^2 + y^2 +z = 128$ and the planes $x=0, x=4, y=0, y=4$. Find the volume of the shape.
**My attempt:**
$4x^2 + y^2 +z = 128 \implies z = 128-4x^2-y^2$, then
$$V=\int_{0}^{4}\int_{0}^{4}128-4x^2-y^2\,dydx=\frac{4864}{3}$$
Now, I want to do this with a triple-integral. My problem is with the lower bound for $z$.My initial thought would be $z=48$, where $x=4 \land y=4$, but I got a different answer.Through trial and error, I got
$$V=\int_{0}^{4}\int_{0}^{4}\int_{\color{red}{0}}^{128-4x^2-y^2}dzdydx=\frac{4864}{3}$$
**Question:** Why is the lower bound $z=0$ (in red)? The elliptical function $z = 128-4x^2-y^2$ is unbounded below.

Comment: The question should state the lower bound of $z$ otherwise $z$ is not bound below and the volume is not finite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comment by Math Lover is correct.

In the first attempt, even though you don't explicitly set a lower bound on $z$ of $0$, you are implicitly doing so with the integrand: the function $128-4x^2-y^2$ gives the distance between the value of $z$ at the top of the region and $0$. The volume is unbounded unless we add the plane $z=0$ to the problem conditions.

Comment: That's what I thought. However, I'm having trouble seeing how $128-4x^2-y^2$ gives the distance between $z$ and 0?

Comment: If $z$ takes the value $128-4x^2-y^2$, then $z-0 = 128-4x^2-y^2-0 = 128-4x^2-y^2$. I should say the distance between the value of $z$ at the top of the region and $0$.

Comment: Can I argue that since $0\le x \le 4$ and $0\le y\le 4 \therefore 48\le z \le 128?$

Comment: That is correct for the surface - $z$ has its maximum value $128$ at $(0,0)$ and its minimum value $48$ on the quarter circle $x^2+y^2=4$. But the actual region is unbounded below since the problem never specified a bottom plane as a boundary. The value of $z$ can go to $-\infty$ in the region, but on the surface itself it can only go as low as $48$.

Comment: Now, I understand. Thank you for the quick responses.

Comment: no problem - happy to help :)